# What does 'Magic number does not match' mean when installing software?

Tags: 12.04, installation, vmware

I downloaded `VMware-Player-5.0.1-894247.i386.bundle` but when I tried to install it from the terminal I got

```
Magic number does not match
```

I use Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit with 2Gb ram.

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen Don't do that again.

Comment: lol, I get what this community is about then.

Answer (score 6):

`Magic number does not match` seems to indicate that your download did not go correctly. Please re-download and try again.

[Source 1](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1081576) and [source 2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1519092)

If you know the hash for the file you can use [`md5sum`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) to check your download.

Comment: I just wonder where can I get the checksum from vmware..